# Change the structure of a PostgreSQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

I have the below PostgreSQL query which basically returns a recommendation list based on the hard-coded product name (misspelled on purpose).

There are 4 tables -

Products_list

```
Column     |          Type          | Modifiers
---------+------------------------+-----------
productid | integer                | not null
name      | character varying(400) | not null
year      | character varying(100) | not null
```

Categories

```
 Column    |         Type          | Modifiers
---------+-----------------------+-----------
 productid | integer               | not null
 category  | character varying(50) | not null
```

Companies

```
Column   |          Type          |   Modifiers            
---------+------------------------+------------
compid  | integer                | not null
c_name  | character varying(250) | not null
```

Prod_com

```
Column  |  Type   | Modifiers
---------+---------+-----------
productid | integer |
compid | integer |
```

User enters a misspelled product name, I will find the closest matching product name, then find the corresponding category and the company that produces the product and recommend the list of products which is produced by the same company belonging to the same category.

```
With 
product_name as (
select name,productid
from products_list
group by name,productid
having levenshtein(name, 'Acryn')<=3
order by levenshtein(name, 'Acryn')
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
),
cat_name as( 
select distinct category, c.productid productid
from product_name m, categories c
where m.productid=c.productid 
),
com_name as(
select distinct c_name,a.compid compid
from companies a, prod_com pc, product_name m
where pc.productid = m.productid and pc.compid=a.compid 
LIMIT 2)
select distinct name,year
from products_list pl, cat_name cn, com_name co, prod_com pc,categories c
where co.compid=pc.compid and c.category = cn.category and 
c.productid = pl.productid and pl.productid = pc.productid
limit 10;
```

One of the students in my class has already used a similar WITH clause approach and my professor wants me to do it in a different way. I have put way too much effort into this and I don't know how to change the query structure, so that it does the same job as the above query.

Could somebody be kind and help me out in re-structuring this query so that it works the same way? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds iffy that you would know how to use the with, but not how to write the base query. The conversion is extremely easy, just read through the manual. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html. Besides, you should learn the sql standard way of doing this, as WITH is not supported by all sql flavors.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:mysql]?

Comment: WITH is also not supported by mysql BTW.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
foo as (select subquery)
select bar from foo
```

is equivalent to

```
select bar from (select subquery) as foo
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html